# WPF DataGrid column binding overridden by auto generated columns

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm using DataGrid from WPF Toolkit - The latest one. But the below code is not working

XAML code

```
    <dg:DataGrid 
    Grid.Row="1"
    Name="eventLogGrid"
    Margin="5,0,5,0"
    BorderBrush="Black"
    ItemsSource="{Binding EventLogs}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    IsReadOnly="True">
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn
            Binding="{Binding EventID}" Header="Event ID" />
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn
            Binding="{Binding Server}" Header="Server" />
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn
            Binding="{Binding Source}" Header="Source" />
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn
            Binding="{Binding Logged}" Header="Logged" />
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>

</dg:DataGrid>
```

C# code

```
public class EventLogItem
{
    public long EventID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Server Server { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public EventLogEntryType Level { get; set; }
    public DateTime Logged { get; set; }
    public string Machine { get; set; }
}
public List<EventLogItem> EventLogs
{
    get { return (List<EventLogItem>)GetValue(EventLogsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EventLogsProperty, value); 
}
```

The real issue here is that although I specified the columns and its binding in the xaml code, but when the data arrived, every property is occupying a column. The desired effect is that only thosed bound properties are shown.

Comment: what are the [binding errors](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/486)

Comment: Is the binding just not being notified of new elements added to the collection? What happens if you use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`?

Comment: Ok, I'll try using that. The issue here is that when I set the EventLogs property, all the properties are shown instead of those 4 columns I'm binding which is really really frustrating.

Comment: Ah, in that case, just set `AutoGenerateColumns = "False"` in your DataGrid declaration.

Comment: You are my hero. That did the trick. Talking about me being dumb here. I wrote the code based on a sample, but missed the important one little thing - AutoGenerateColumns - it seemed useless to me at the time.

Comment: How can I give you points? Can I mark a comment as accepted? Or you could just wrote an answer and I'll upvote and accept

Comment: @imgen I just added it as an answer, thanks for reminding me. Also, if you don't mind, it might be a nice idea to edit your question to better reflect the problem (unexpected columns), so that those with similar problems in the future can benefit from this question too!

Comment: Thx for your suggestion and I already updated the question to be more precise about the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrid has a property `AutoGenerateColumns`, which is by default set to true, giving you the extra columns that you don't expect. Just set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` in your xaml declaration for DataGrid and you will get only the specified columns.

(Personally, I've always found this more of an annoyance than a convenience too!)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set `DataGrid`'s `AutoGenerateColumns` = `true`, define a simple `Behavior<DataGrid>` Class that Handles the `AutoGeneratingColumn` Event and use `System.ComponentModel`'s `DisplayName` Attribute on each Column's Bound Property to specify a custom Column Header (and/or other Column Properties) or suppress the Column (by not having an Attribute).  See this great and simple solution here: [A Smart Behavior for DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/389764/A-Smart-Behavior-for-DataGrid-AutoGenerateColumn).  Btw, I also just noticed that Xceed's `DataGridControl` automatically (without you having to define a `Behavior<DataGridControl>` Class) uses a `DisplayName` Attribute (if any) to override the Column Header.  However, it will not suppress the Column if the Attribute's not there (and I've not researched if they support auto-generated Column suppression in other ways).  I semi-hacked it by handling the View's `Loaded` Event and setting Columns' `Visible` Property to `false` whose `Title` is some Constant that represents it should be suppressed (i.e. "_").